# Python BeautifulSoup cURL no connection

Tags: python, xml, curl, beautifulsoup

I am connecting to an XML page via proxy using cURL. For some reason there is no connection to the page. Parsing isn't an issue so I will not include it with the code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time  #added for curl
import subprocess #added for curl
import os #added for curl
file_name = raw_input("Type the name of the new file you will create: ")
g = open(file_name+".txt",'w')
g.write("---XML Parse---\n")
curlURL= 'F:\Downloads\curl-7.31.0-rtmp-ssh2-ssl-sspi-zlib-idn-static-bin-w32\curl.exe'
with open("list.txt") as f: #file from which information will be read and used in link
    for line in f:
        g.write("\nPage ID: "+line.rstrip('\n')+"\n")
        link = "https://somewebsite.com/+line.rstrip('\n')"
        args = (curlURL+ ' -L ' +link+ ' -o c:\\temp.txt --proxy-ntlm -x http://myproxy:80 -k -U:') #using a proxy
        print args
        sp = subprocess.Popen(args) #run curl
        sp.wait() #Wait for it to finish before proceeding
        xml_string = open('C:/temp.txt', 'r').read() #read in the temporary file
        time.sleep(3)
        os.remove('C:/temp.txt') # clean up
        soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_string)
        result = soup.find('bibliographic-data')
        if result is not None:
            status = result['status']
            g.write("\nApplication Status: "+status+"\n")
            g.write("Most Recent Event Information: \n")

#...i go on to parse the document
```

I am getting the error:

```
curl:(56) Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Any idea why i am being denied access?

Comment: Have you tried [`requests`](http://python-requests.org/) instead? I suspect that it can handle your firewall just fine.

Comment: I would prefer not to change at this point, just address the issue of the current error. Unless you think the location of the temp file is firewall related, i shouldn't be as it is on my current machine.

Comment: No, the tmp file is not firewall related. I thought I'd give you an easier option than running cURL as a command-line tool and fighting the types of problems that brings with it.

Comment: I will attempt it that way as well, but for the time being do you have any idea why this temp file is not being opened for reading of the XML?

Comment: Nope; according to the error there *is* no `temp.txt` file.

Comment: And if you *do* try `requests`, don't forget to include the [ntlm support extension](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm).

Comment: Shouldn't it *create* a temp file, use it to read the xml, then dispose of it as does `g = open(file_name+".txt",'w')` ? How should I go about this if not?

Comment: Sorry, no idea; I don't see anything obviously wrong but curl does not appear to download your file.

Comment: Could it be that i'm not opening it correctly in the curl link or removing it from os at the wrong time?

Comment: I don't think you are removing it at the wrong time; I'd put in a breakpoint there and double-check that cURL succeeded or not.

Comment: Yes the temp file is definitely nonexistant because the curl does not succeed, so I know my issue is with curl. Investigating more now.

Comment: Question rephrased to address the issue at hand, the temp file wasn't the real issue.